# Hello, I was working today on tensorflow with R language. library(tensorflow)

Tags: r, tensorflow

I was working today on **tensorflow** with **R language**.

But I typed those lines of the code after installing the package of tensorflow:

```
library(tensorflow)
sess = tf$Session()
hello <- tf$constant("Hello, TensorFlow!")
```

But I got this error message :

```
Error in class(obj) <- "rs.scalar" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

Does anyone of you know what does it mean ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the python `tensorflow` library installed?

Comment: I got the same error message from the line hello <- tf$constant("Hello, TensorFlow!"). I followed the install instruction: 1. devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow") 2. 
library(tensorflow). 3. 
install_tensorflow(). But sess$run(hello) run OK.

Answer (score 3):

After loading the `tensorflow`, we need to use `install_tensorflow`

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
#Using r-tensorflow conda environment for TensorFlow installation
##Determining latest release of TensorFlow...done
#Installing TensorFlow...
#---
#---
#---
#[freetype            ]|#####################################             |  75%
#[h5py                ]|########################################          |  81%
#[scipy               ]|###########################################       |  87%
#[pillow              ]|##############################################    |  93%
#[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100% 
#Installation of TensorFlow complete.
```

Then start the `Session`

```
sess = tf$Session()
hello <- tf$constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess$run(hello)
#b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

Answer (score 0):

HI I have a workaround method

save your code into an R script file say abc.R

Open shell from RStudio and execute "R CMD BATCH abc.R"

or system("R CMD BATCH abc.R") on RStudio